# cURL - Timstamp for the request and response while collect data from a sensor

Tags: c++, curl, timestamp, libcurl

I have the following set of `cURL` commands in my `C++` code:

```
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "Dummy_Address");
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data.c_str());
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, data.length());
            const boost::posix_time::ptime request_time = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
            const boost::posix_time::ptime response_time = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

I have two variables: `request_time` and `response_time`, to note the timestamps at which data is requested and response is received. My earlier understanding was that the `CURLOPT_POST` is responsible for sending the request while `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` invokes `WriteCallback` when a response is received. That's the reason why I am noting down timestamps near these two commands. However, after reading further into `cURL` documentation, I feel that the actual execution is done by `curl_easy_perform`. Am I right in changing the code as shown below to collect the correct timestamps?

```
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "Dummy_Address");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, data.length());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        const boost::posix_time::ptime request_time = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        const boost::posix_time::ptime response_time = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
```

Comment: Yes, all the work is done by `curl_easy_perform`. Everything else just stores the various pieces of data, for `curl_easy_perform` to use.

Comment: Thank You. If you could please write it as an answer, I could accept it and close the question. I am inexperienced with `cURL` and that was the primary reason for the question.